# list of all locale for localization on Android

Tags: android, localization

I was looking for a list of all available locale constants for Android. I can only find the short one on the ref page. Is there a list somewhere available or do I have to manually get the locale constant for each language manually by testing each individual language?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list here, although I'm not sure it's complete:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596004